# git sweep - fatal: malformed object name master

Tags: git

For some reason, I'm no longer able to run

```
git sweep
```

as I'm getting this error

```
fatal: malformed object name master
fatal: branch name required
```

Can't seem to find anything about this particular problem online so wondered if anyone might have come across it? I changed the default branch by running this (which I'm guessing is now causing the problem)

```
 git config --global --add init.defaultBranch main
```

Comment: `git sweep` is not a standard Git command, so unless you tell us where you got it, there's probably not much anyone can say here. Are you referring to https://github.com/arc90/git-sweep?

Comment: Thanks @torek. I didn't realise it wasn't a standard Git command. Explains why I couldn't find much about it! It wasn't from the link you posted but I picked it up elsewhere. Knowing that, I dug a little deeper and found a section in my .gitconfig file that was still referring to 'master' after I'd changed the main branch to 'main'. All good now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

*Obviously you found the answer to your personal problem.
As this comes up as one of the first search results, I'd like to leave a more general answer for the next visitors:*

gits `malformed object`-error relates to a reference not being available **locally** to git.
In case of OP he lacked the local reference `master` due to its replacement by `main`.

This error does also occur if one uses e.g. git-tags´ `--merged`-filter for branches which, while available on a remote, have not been created by e.g. a checkout locally yet.
If OPs `master`-branch would have been available on origin, the error for such a filter issue could have been resolved by using `origin/master` instead of `master´.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my .gitconfig file has this in it

```
# Clean merged branches
  sweep = !git branch --merged master | grep -v 'master$' | xargs git branch -d && git remote prune origin
```

Changed 'master' to 'main' and all is well.